# How to sign and send a Mimultipart message in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, m2crypto, smime

Typically, sending a message with attachments is performed like this in python.

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=None,
              server="127.0.0.1"):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(msg, 'html'))

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(f)
            )
        # After the file is closed
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string()) # The problem is here
    smtp.close()
```

However, I cannot perform that since the part to be signed with ꜱᴍɪᴍᴇ is only the body and attachments, not all metadata.

In such situation, I would need to split message and Metadata. However, I still need to use `email.mime.multipart` and email.mime.application`` for constructing attachments metadata (while excluding other metadata)

So how to create an ʜᴛᴍʟ e‑mail with attachments while still using ʜᴛᴍʟ formatting and attachments ?

Comment: I know have an additional problem : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51182176